# Information Bottleneck - Calculating the Mutual information between the Labels and the Features

Tags: machine-learning, it.information-theory, lg.learning, shannon-entropy

I am trying to understand the [Nonlinear Information Bottlecneck paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02436) along with [their implementation](https://github.com/artemyk/nonlinearIB/blob/8913c1b75fa573c8d386516ba0fc52d9e9d088de/code/mnistdemo.py), but I am confused as to what is actually being calculated in the Mutual information $(I(Y, M))$ between the Target ($Y$) and the Features ($M$).

$$I(Y, M) = H(Y) - H(Y|M) $$

I was under the impression that in the Information Bottleneck method, we want to maximize $I(Y, M)$ (and minimize  $I(X, M)$, but I won't look at that in this question). In a simple MNIST classification problem, this would translate to maximizing the mutual information between the class distribution (which is discrete and uniform), and the latent feature distribution (continuous).

However, in the example code, the conditional entropy ($H(Y|M)$) seems to be calculated between the prediction $\hat{Y}$ and the target $Y$, rather than the conditional entropy between the feature $M$ and the target $Y$ ([see code here](https://github.com/artemyk/nonlinearIB/blob/8913c1b75fa573c8d386516ba0fc52d9e9d088de/code/mnistdemo.py#L51)).

I thought the goal was to produce informative features, not informative predictions.

They say as well in the paper :

> "To implement the decoding map $P_{\phi}(y|m)$, the bottleneck layer states are passed through several deterministic neural network layers with parameters $\phi$." (Page 12)

I understand this as being fixed network layers that don't get updated in training. Am I mistaken?   Because in the implementation, the decoding layers are trainable ([see code here](https://github.com/artemyk/nonlinearIB/blob/8913c1b75fa573c8d386516ba0fc52d9e9d088de/code/mnistdemo.py#L43)).

This adds to my confusion because, in their implementation, it seems like they are calculating $I(Y, \hat{Y})$ (*which is essentially categorical cross entropy*), rather than $I(Y, M)$.

What am I missing?

Thank you,

Liam

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53039/5038, https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/41157/1794, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/620630/2921.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer. I might update it if I decide to look at the implementation.

> I understand this as being fixed network layers that don't get updated
> in training. Am I mistaken?

Note that the mutual information is being estimated **after** an epoch. *At this point* the weights of the layers are fixed. Hence, the output of each layer is deterministic.